# Function to calculate month end in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table which has `PlanTotal` (how many plans), `PlanStartDate` (start date of plan) and `PlanInstallment` columns which tell me how many monthly payments the plan has left.

What coding would I need to work out

1. the date the plan will end and
2. how many plans are due to finish after today's date?

I also need to factor in that the `PlanStartDate` is in numeric value not `datetime`, so would need to convert this as well in the code.

Any help/ advice appreciated!

Comment: which database you are working on and give some sample data.

Comment: This is very vague. You are not even telling us what a plan is supposed to be. What have you tried? What specific problem are you encountering? Must we guess?

Comment: Have you told a programmer or DBA of your request; perhaps they can come up with a technical solution for you; they'll probably want you to give them a lot more detail of exactly what you'd like them to write, however.

Comment: Sorry if I was being vague, I'm quite new to coding. It's a table for a payment plan, so it gives me a payment start date and how many monthly payments they have left to pay. So I currently have this; SELECT [PlanTotal]
      ,[PlanInstallments]
      
      ,[PlanStartDate]
      
      
  FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Plans]                 but not sure what type of code I need to work out the end date.

Comment: Please give an extract of your data as an example e.g. column names + some data rows so we can see how your table is set up

Answer (score 0):

Here are many ways to format dates. I took GetDate() as the exemple.

```
DECLARE @NumericDate AS INT

SET @NumericDate = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) AS INT)

SELECT GETDATE() Today, 
       CONVERT(INT,GETDATE(),112) DateInt, 
       CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) AS INT) DateNumeric, 
       YEAR(GETDATE())*10000 + MONTH(GETDATE())*100 + DAY(GETDATE()) AS DateNumeric_V2,
       CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),121) DateChar, 
       DATEADD(day,DAY(GETDATE())*-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE())) AS LastDayOfCurrentMonth,
       SUBSTRING(CAST(@NumericDate AS CHAR(8)),1,4) 
        + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@NumericDate AS CHAR(8)),5,2) 
        + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@NumericDate AS CHAR(8)),7,2) AS NumericDate_2_String
```

And for the end date calculation you have DATEADD()

```
DECLARE @PlanInstallment as int
DECLARE @PlanStartDate AS INT

SET @PlanInstallment = 4
SET @PlanStartDate = 20140317

SELECT @PlanStartDate AS PlanStartDate,
       DATEADD(MONTH,@PlanInstallment,GETDATE()) AS PlanEndDate
```

So with a mix of those 2 queries you should be able to do anything you want.